# JavaScript/Google Maps - map.fitBounds doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to fit the bounds of the map after drawing the route on Google Maps, for some reason the below does not get applied, it seems that it's ignored, I've even tried to set manual zoom, it was ignored too:

```
       var bounds = response.routes[0].bounds;
       this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Here is the current result:[image]

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pickUp.formattedAddress,
    destination: dropOff.formattedAddress,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {

       var bounds = response.routes[0].bounds;
       this.map.fitBounds(bounds);

    } else {
      console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: According to [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) the fitBounds() function "Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds.".  It looks like the route is within the map viewport to me.

Comment: You mean it can not be zoomed more than that ?

Comment: I think you might be looking for `panToBounds()`.  Man.. don't you wish there was some kind of [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) for this stuff??

Comment: I've tried a bunch of stuff, believe me, I've spent more than 8 hours without any progress. This is my last hope, and I wish I can find a solution

Comment: By the way `panToBounds()` didn't work too

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, what do you mean by "map.fitBounds doesn't work"?